# Writing Python Code to Calculate Total Pay, Including Overtime

Tags: python

I've written what seems like perfect code, to me, to calculate overtime hours.

Yet Coursera keeps telling me that I'm wrong. Could someone look at this and tell me what, exactly, I am doing wrong?

I want to find the solution myself and I've tried but I just don't see what's wrong! I'm sure everyone (but me) is familiar with the problem.

I need to write code that will calculate pay for someone who has worked over 40 hours. He (or she) gets $10.50 for the first 40 hours and then time and a half. Supposedly, this particular person has worked 45 hours.

I get the right total amount ($498.75) but, still, somehow, I'm wrong.

```
hrs = raw_input("Enter Hours:")
h = float(hrs)

rate = raw_input("Enter Rate:")
r = float(rate)

pay = h*r
ifh = ("raw_input<=40")

print pay
ifh = ("raw_input>40")

pay = (40*r)+(h-40)*(1.5*r)
print pay
```

Comment: Aside from poorly formatted code, do you really need to get the rate as an input if it is given as a constant of the problem?

Comment: What are the actual specifications of the problem? Are you sure it wants you to get the data via input, and print the result? Seems more likely they want you to write a function which accepts hours/rate as parameters, and *return* the result.

Comment: Plus, I have no idea what you think `ifh=("raw_input<=40")` is doing, but it is creating a new string called `ifh` and giving it the value "raw_input<=40". Seems unlikely that is what is required, especially as you then ignore it.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman I apologise for not stating the problem more clearly. Coursera won't allow me to put a space between "if" and "h". The code runs perfectly on the Coursera page in that it provides the correct answer BUT it also provides an INCORRECT answer. The correct answer is $498.50 (40*10.50)+(5*10.50*1.50) for a total of 45  hours. The additional answer is $472.50, which is 45*10.50. The code clearly states that, in the first case, h must be less than or equal to 40. There is no instruction to do h*r where h is greater than 40 in the first instance. If it is there, then I can't see it.

Comment: Coursera is presumably reporting that you have a syntax error, which you do; `=` is for assignment, not comparison, which would be `==`. But of course you still have several major problems, including the fact that your condition is in a string, the lack of a colon at the end, and most significant of all, the indentation.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. But I don't understand your answer in that I don't know where I should replace = with == or where I should put a colon that I haven't. I cannot indent because Coursera gives me a ParseError message the moment I indent.

Comment: I found the error at last! To indent the line after the if line, I had to create a blank line before the if line. Everything else was perfect! Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 1):

I would say that your first 5 steps are correct however your syntax for your if statement is not correct:

```
ifh = ("raw_input<=40")
```

I believe what you want to code is:

```
if h <= 40:
    print pay

if h > 40:
    pay = (40*r)+(h-40)*(1.5*r)
    print pay
```

Comment: even better: `if .. else ..`

Comment: I tried what you said. When I indent 4 spaces,in the print pay line, I get a message: ParseError Bad input on line 7. I typed everything exactly as you have, here, keeping the rest of my code intact.

Comment: A parse error is a syntax error I suggest you use an IDE to help you find the syntax error. Did you remember to add the ":" that Kevin kindly added for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
hrs = raw_input("Enter Hours:")
h = float(hrs)

rate = raw_input("Enter Rate:")
r = float(rate)

pay = h*r
if h<=40:

    print pay
if h > 40:

    pay = (40*r)+(h-40)*(1.5*r)
    print pay
```